# Stop dynamic div to push other elements

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following:

```
Text text text2 text text
text text text text text.
```

At some point I am replacing this to this:

```
Text text <div class="highlight" style="background-color:red;">text2</div> text text
text text text text text.
```

But it pushes the text, how can I make it stay in the same order as before?

This is what I tried:

```
float:left;
```

And

```
parent().css('overflow', 'auto');
```

It didn't work.
Do you know any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two solutions:

1) Just use `span` instead of `div`

2) You can use `div` but you have to define the following style

```
div.highlight {
  display:inline;  
}
```

Here you can find a demo of the second solution: http://jsfiddle.net/smWvA/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use span instead of div

```
Text text <span class="highlight" style="background-color:red;">text2</span> text text
text text text text text.
```

Answer (score 1):

Div has `display:block` as default and that is whats cousing that effects.

So you could use `SPAN` insteed which has `inline` as default for the property `display`

If you want to read more about the display property have a look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

Comment: I'm completly wrong ^^ Div has display block, SPAN have display:inline ;-) I'm updated my answer ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls check if the class-highlight doesn't have any parent css which it inherits. Try seeing the "Computed Style" for text2.

Google Chrome :
 <kbd>F12</kbd>, locate your element
 or
 simple right click the text2 and inspect Element.

The Computed Style is on the top right of the inspect element window

Answer (score 0):

I made an example on jsfiddle. If you decide to use div you must specify display: inline or inline-block. Span is inline by default, so it's better to use span here...

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3L2K6/